# Bootstrap - Force Div to Next Line when after Text area

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a feeling there is a quick solution to this but I'm stumped.

I have a simple layout, 2 col image, 4 col text, 2 col image, 4 col text.

https://codepen.io/brianpensinger/pen/GEbxxv

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/000/fff"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/000/fff"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When on the SM breakpoint, I want to switch to 6 col each. However, my second image sits underneath the text instead of going to a new line.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGLoh.png)

How can I force it down to the next line?

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of `cleafix` issue caused due to `float:left` on `cols`. You can do it manually by writing a `CSS` for that specific `SM` viewport or simply add `HTML` for `clearfix` which only works in `SM` viewport.

Check the snippet.

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/000/fff"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui.
      Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis
      quis ac lectus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>

    <!-- ############## Added Clearfix for SM view ############# -->
    <div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div>


    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/000/fff"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui.
      Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis
      quis ac lectus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the super quick reply and the clear help! I truly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Hi there!

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/000/fff"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-8">Text here</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x300/000/fff"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-8">Text here</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

This will do what you require :) By giving defining the first row you have told it to be one block. By defining the cols inside you have told to take up 50% of the page in md/lg. After that they will automatically go to full width which is where you were ultimately having the problem.

To combat that you could define another row. By defining another row you have told bootstrap to take up 100% of the containers width... since the col above is no longer valid past md size it then has full reign over the 100%. This will give you 6/6, one below the other.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used the other commentors answer but I truly appreciate you jumping in with this help!